# Can't access needed object attribute within Javascript Find

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I have an object nested in a list of lists that I'm trying to access.

The structure is like this:

```
list = [[], [{accountID: 123}], [], []]
```

I can access the needed object by console logging it hard-coded, like this:

```
console.log(list[0][0].accountID)
```

However, when I try to look up the object by a needed value using `.find()`, it always returns undefined:

```
list.find(e => e[0][0].accountID === 123)
```

Switching things around like `list[0].find(e => e[0].accountID === 123)`, list[0][0].find etc. doesn't work either.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Ideally, I'd also like to avoid hard-coding the indexes, but I've done it here to confirm that the attribute is where I think it is.

Comment: `list.flat().find(o => o.accountID === 123)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` will loop the array, if you use `list.find((e) => console.log(e));` you will see the output.

```
[]
[ { accountID: 123 } ]
[]
[]
```

Use `e[0]?.accountID` to select the object you need.

```js
list.find((e) => e[0]?.accountID === 123);
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.find(e => e[0][0].accountID === 123)` returns undefined because the find() method returns the first element in the array satisfying testing function.

You can use the find() method on the inner arrays as well, e.g.

```
const foundObj = list.flatMap(arr => arr)
                    .find(obj => obj && obj.accountID === 123);
```

Answer (score 0):

the comparison `[0].accountID === 123` is not possible on all the elements of the list because they do not all have an `accountID` property, which generates a runtime error.

You can use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to solve this problem

```js
const list = [[], [{accountID: 123}], [], []];

console.log(list[1][0].accountID);  
 //              ^---- index value is 1
 
 
let res = list.find(e => e[0]?.accountID === 123);
//                           ^----use Optional Chaining 
console.log( res );
```